# Why does this error state my class does not implement this interface method?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, interface, return-type

I have a class that implements an interface and legacy from other class.

I don't know why my code is bad.

The error I get is:

```
CS0738 'SizeTypeService' does not implement interface member 'IGenericService<ItemType>.GetAll()'.

'GenericService<SizeType>.GetAll()' cannot implement 'IGenericService<ItemType>.GetAll()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'Task<List<ItemType>>'.
```

I think that my interface and class are ok. I don't know why VS is throwing an error.

```csharp
public interface IGenericService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll();
    Task<TEntity> GetById(int id);
    Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity entity);
    Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity);
    Task Delete(int id);
}

public class GenericService<TEntity> : IGenericService<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private IGenericRepository<TEntity> genericRepository;

    public GenericService(IGenericRepository<TEntity> genericRepository)
    {
        this.genericRepository = genericRepository;
    }

    public async Task Delete(int id)
    {
        await genericRepository.Delete(id);
    }

    public async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll()
    {
        return await genericRepository.GetAll();
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await genericRepository.GetById(id);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        return await genericRepository.Insert(entity);
    }

    public async Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        return await genericRepository.Update(entity);
    }
}

public interface ISizeTypeService : IGenericService<ItemType>
{
    Task<List<SizeType>> GetAllSizeTypeActives(int id);
    Task LogicDelete(int id);
}

public class SizeTypeService : GenericService<SizeType>, ISizeTypeService
{
    private ISizeTypeRepository sizeTypeRepository;

    public SizeTypeService(ISizeTypeRepository sizeTypeRepository) : base(sizeTypeRepository)
    {
        this.sizeTypeRepository = sizeTypeRepository;
    }

    public Task<List<SizeType>> GetAllSizeTypeActives(int id)
    {
        return sizeTypeRepository.GetAllSizeTypeActives(id);
    }

    public Task LogicDelete(int id)
    {
        return sizeTypeRepository.LogicDelete(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at: `class SizeTypeService: GenericService<SizeType>, ISizeTypeService`.  Your `ISizeTypeService` inherits from `IGenericService<ItemType>` while your class inherits from `GenericService<SizeType>` which implements `IGenericService<SizeType>`.  I think you need to have a second implementation of `IGenericService`.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined your `ServiceTypeClass` as

```
public class SizeTypeService : GenericService<SizeType>, ISizeTypeService
{
   ...
}
```

So you are telling the compiler that `ServiceTypeService` uses the base class `GenericService` with `TEntity` defined as `SizeType`. BUT, the `ISizeTypeService` interface it also derives from is telling the compiler that this class also implements the `IGenericService` interface where `TEntity` is a `ItemType` class. But nowhere in the code is class that implements the method `GenericService<ItemType>.GetAll()`.

So, the error is saying "hey - I found the method matching `GenericService<SizeType>.GetAll()` - where `TEntity` is `SizeType`, but I cannot find one that matches `IGenericService<ItemType>.GetAll()`"

To fix you need to change the `ISizeTypeService` definition to use the same class as `GenericService` for `TEntity`

e.g.

```
public interface ISizeTypeService : IGenericService<SizeType>
{
   ...
}
```

NOTE: The generic parameter is now `SizeType` which matches the `GenericService<SizeType>` base class that `SizeTypeService` derives from.

Comment: Or implement the `ISizeTypeService` interface explicitly.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Absolutely!! I made the assumption that the OP wanted only `SizeType` for `TEntity` but you are correct that they could implement the interface explicitly if they wanted to use both :-)

Comment: thank you!!! It was an erratum!! I want to write IGenericService<SizeType>. But I couldn't see that. Thank my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Simply Ged explained clearly. As code in your ISizeTypeService

```
public interface ISizeTypeService: IGenericService<ItemType>
    {
    }
```

Because you get  Task<List> IGenericRepository.GetAll() in  GenericService.
So

[image]

I also got a similar error, then I added the following code in SizeTypeService.cs and the error went away

```
Task<List<ItemType>> IGenericService<ItemType>.GetAll()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```